# Can a SwiftUI document based app show Firestore documents in the SwiftUI document browser directly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller, uidocumentpicker

Using Swift 5.3.1, Xcode 12.2, iOS 14.2.

Is it possible to directly access Firestore documents from within a `DocumentGroup` based iOS app?

I know that you can show the document browser with iOS 14 and SwiftUI. And it is also able to show iCloud or custom cloud documents.

But I wonder if Firestore can be the external cloud for your custom-typed document picker in iOS?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

Cloud Firestore is a document-based NoSQL database in the cloud, and it is intended to be used by developers to build their own apps. A document in Cloud Firestore refers to a unit of information that is meaningful in the context of an application. It is not to be confused with a document in the sense of a container for data on your file system or in iCloud. In this sense, it is much more similar to [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html).

That being said, you would definitely be able to implement a [File Provider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) that uses Cloud Firestore to store present your application's data in a representation that is meaningful to iOS apps that consume files. However, it might be more useful to use [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) as the backend for this kind of app.

I'd be curious about your use case - can you elaborate a bit more what you're aiming to achieve?

Comment: Thank you Peter, for your explanations. Indeed, we use Firestore AND  Firebase/Storage. We use Firestore for our Media-collection as well as references to other relevant Firestore-collections related to the Media (to keep query-times short as NoSQL best practices). In addition, this Firestore-Media-collection holds a path-field for the corresponding Firebase/Storage image or video.  This path-field in the Firestore Media-collection is then used if a Firestore-query leads to Media-results that, for example, need to be downloaded (or potentially shown in the Document-Picker in the first place).

Comment: Therefore, I do not intend to open-up the App Document-Picker for all Firebase/Storage images and videos at once - but I would much rather open up the App Document-Picker for queried Firestore Media-results that then are shown to be picked by the user. Does this make sense ?  Is there another architecture that you would suggest to allow the Document-Picker being limited to a subset of Media from the Firebase/Storage bucket to be in-line with a query-result subset ?